# Django related_name following backwards

Tags: django

I have the following model in Django:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    solution=models.ForeignKey(Solution, related_name='solution1')
    idea=models.ForeignKey(Idea,null=True, blank=True,related_name='idea1')
    idea2=models.ForeignKey(Idea, related_name='idea2')
```

Given the ID of a solution how can I write a query that would retrieve me all ideas2 that have been in the feedbacks with this solution. And I am wondering is it even possible in Django. Thanks a lot!
 I tried something like this, but how can I specify that I am looking for idea2, not idea1?

```
ideas2= Idea.objects.filter(feedback_solution1=solutionID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
feedbacks = list(Feedback.objects.filter(solution=solutionID).values_list('idea2__pk', flat=True))
ideas2 = Idea.objects.filter(pk__in=feedbacks)
```

Or

```
feedbacks = list(Feedback.objects.filter(solution=solutionID).values_list('idea2__pk', flat=True))
ideas2 = Idea.objects.in_bulk(feedbacks)
```

Check out the Performance considerations section in the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

Comment: no need of the explicit `list()` casting. The `values_list(.., flat=True)` is already returning a list type

Comment: @karthikr `values_list` returns a `ValuesListQuerySet`, not a list. Without the `list()` casting, Django will do a subquery, with the `list()` it will fetch the `idea2__pk` values in a separate query.

Comment: Like I said in my solution, check out the performance considerations, it explains why you should probably use list()

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list @Alasdair.

Comment: @karthikr try doing a `values_list` query in the shell, and check the type of the result. You will see it's a `ValuesListQuerySet` instance. I don't see anything in the docs that contradicts that.

Comment: I agree with you sir.. But `values_list(.., flat=True)` gives you a list. Thats all i am trying to say @Alasdair

Comment: @karthkir Try `type(MyModels.objects.values_list('field', flat=True) `. It will give you `ValuesListQuerySet`, and not `list`.